# How to extract entities in text prompt using bot framework sdk for node.js?

Tags: botframework

I'm developing a bot using the bot framework for node.js v4. Imagine the following scenario:

user: Hello

bot: How can I help you?

user: What is the deadline for completing the transfer?

bot: What is the value of the transfer?

user: $ 5,000

At this time, I am executing the textprompt to request the value of the transfer and I need to validate if the user entity ($ 5,000) has been identified as the money entity.

This is the dialog stack:

```
 this.addDialog(new WaterfallDialog(DUVIDA_NIVEL_APROVACAO_DIALOG, [
        this.initializeStateStep.bind(this),
        this.moneyStep.bind(this),
        this.captureMoney.bind(this),
        this.endConversation.bind(this)
    ]));

this.addDialog(new TextPrompt(MONEY_PROMPT, this.validateMoneyInput));
```

And the validate method:

```
async validateMoneyInput(validatorContext) {
    const value = validatorContext.recognized.value; //how to get entities?
    if (value == 'money') {
        return VALIDATION_SUCCEEDED;
    } else {
        await validatorContext.context.sendActivity(`What is the value of the transfer?`);
        return VALIDATION_FAILED;
    }
}
```

However, in the callback to validate the textprompt, I have only the text sent by the user.

How can I get the entities extracted by Luis within the textprompt validation method?

Answer (score 1):

To get any LUIS results into the dialog waterfall, you first need to capture the results on the turnContext, like so:

```
if (turnContext.activity.type === ActivityTypes.Message) {

    // Returns LUIS matched results
    const results = await this.luisRecognizer.recognize(turnContext);

    // Results are assigned to the turnContext object and is passed into the dialog stack
    turnContext.topIntent = results.luisResult.topScoringIntent;
    turnContext.topIntent.entities = results.luisResult.entities;
    turnContext.topIntent.value = results.luisResult.query;

    // Create a dialog context object.
    const dc = await this.dialogs.createContext(turnContext);

    const utterance = (turnContext.activity.text || '').trim().toLowerCase();
    if (utterance === 'cancel') {
        if (dc.activeDialog) {
            await dc.cancelAllDialogs();
            await dc.context.sendActivity(`Ok... canceled.`);
        } else {
            await dc.context.sendActivity(`Nothing to cancel.`);
        }
    }

    // If the bot has not yet responded, continue processing the current dialog.
    await dc.continueDialog();

    // Start the sample dialog in response to any other input.
    if (!turnContext.responded) {
        await dc.beginDialog(DUVIDA_NIVEL_APROVACAO_DIALOG);
    }
}
```

Now that the results have been passed in, you can access the results via the step.context object, like so:

```
this.dialogs.add(new TextPrompt(MONEY_PROMPT, this.validateMoneyInput.bind(this)));

async moneyStep(step) {
    await step.prompt(MONEY_PROMPT, `What is the value of the transfer?`,
        {
            retryPrompt: 'Try again. What is the value of the transfer?'
        }
    );
}

async validateMoneyInput(step) {
    // LUIS results passed into turnContext are retrieved
    const intent = step.context.topIntent['intent'];

    const entity = step.context.topIntent.entities;
    console.log(entity);

    // Validation based on matched intent
    if (intent == 'Money') {
        return await step.context.sendActivity('Validation succeeded');
    } else if (intent != 'Money') {
        return await step.context.sendActivity('Validation failed');
    }
}
```

I also assigned the entities value to a variable for accessing since you were asking about it.

Hope of help!